# Counting distinct answer values from an "in" function:

Tags: mysql

I want to count how many times people signed up for our annual conference, but I want to count each distinct conference only once (sometimes people sign up for additional functions at a single conference so the activity in their record will show multiple "attendances" for a single conference). The answer table should show no more than 2 in the "# of conf" field:

```
SELECT distinct n.id, n.last_name, n.first_name, count(n.id) as "# of conf" from name n
join activity a
on n.id = a.id
where a.product_code in ('conf_12','conf13') and n.id <>'' and n.last_name <>''
group by n.id, n.last_name, n.first_name
order by n.last_name
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` clause on the `product_code` column from the `activity` table - like in the following:

```
SELECT 
    n.id, n.last_name, n.first_name, 
    count(distinct a.product_code) as "# of conf" 
from 
    name n
    join activity a
        on n.id = a.id
where 
    a.product_code in ('conf_12','conf13') 
    and n.id <>'' 
    and n.last_name <>''
group by 
    n.id, n.last_name, n.first_name
order by 
    n.last_name
```

The `COUNT(DISTINCT somecolumn)` gives you a count of distinct values of `somecolumn` in each of the groups of particular query.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because you were first and you have a well-formatted correct answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much @GordonLinoff. It was just a minute so sorry but thanks for being fair/honest :) Regards.